# Styled Components - why does prop position affect styling?

Tags: styled-components

I'm using styled-components to style a parent and child element in a component:

```
function StyledDemo({
  name,
  light,
  ...props
}) {
  return (
    <Parent {...props}>
      <Child>{name}</Child>
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

I have a `light` prop which is true/false - but I'm having an issue with styling the elements based on the value of that property:

```
const Parent = styled.div`
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;

  ${props => props.light && `
    background-color: #ccc;
  `}
`;
```

The styling only seems to work when I remove the prop being passed into the function individually.

`Parent` element uses correct styling based on `light` prop value when:

```
function StyledDemo({ name, ...props })
```

`Parent` element does NOT use correct styling based on `light` prop value when:

```
function StyledDemo({ name, light, ...props })
```

I can get it all working by setting the prop on the `Parent` and `Child` component, but this doesn't seem like it's the best way:

```
return (
  <Parent {...props} light={light}>
    <Child light={light}>{name}</Child>
  </Parent>
);
```

Is this the correct way to apply styles to components based on props, or is there an issue with my approach?

I have a demo to tinker with if it helps:
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kfcsujw99cjU7ttqgTz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to `styled-components` but to the rest parameter.

When you do the rest operator, any property you "pick" out by name won't be contained in the `...rest` variable. So when you do

```
const Button = ({ light, ...rest }) => ()

<Button light primary />
```

`rest` will only contain the `primary` property, but not `light`, that's now it's own variable.

If you did

```
const Button = ({ ...rest }) => ()

<Button light primary />
```

instead `rest` would also contain `light`.

So in your example, you're picking out `light` from `...props`, so when you pass `{...props}` on to the parent it doesn't contain `light` anymore, so `styled-components` doesn't know it exists! Either you go with your first version, or you have to manually apply it to each component.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for more information about the rest parameter!